# REST Framework: POST a FK, get inline model back

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `rest_framework.ViewSet` using an inline Serializer (BarSerializer) to display my Bar model together with my Foo model.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        bar = BarSerializer()

        class Meta:
            model = Foo
            fields = ("name", "bar")
```

A call to `/api/foos/1/` returns:

```
{
    "bar": {"name": "bar", "number": 1}, 
    "name": "up"
}
```

However, I want to create new Foos with Bars referenced by foreignkey.

POST to `/api/foos/`creates a new Foo.

```
{
    "bar": 1, 
    "name": "up"
}
```

This seems to be impossible with a standard ViewSet. In an ideal world I'd POST with a ForeignKey and get the "inlined" model back.

Currently I'm overriding `get_serializer_class` and the create `methods` to return different serializers for each request. Since this seems like a fairly common use case, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below snippet, you can serialize the PK value into required data and while saving you can give only PK value

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, ValidationError
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from rest_framework import serializers

class CustomRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    """
    Represents a primary key relationship with {'pk':1,'name': 'foo'}
    """
    read_only = False

    default_error_messages = {
        'does_not_exist': ("Invalid pk '%s' - object does not exist."),
        'incorrect_type': ('Incorrect type.  Expected {"id": 1} format , received %s.'),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields = kwargs.pop('fields', ('id',))
        return super(CustomRelatedField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def to_native(self, obj):
        data = {'id':obj.pk}
        for field in self.fields:
            value = getattr(obj, field)
            data[field] = value
        return data

    def from_native(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, int):
            data = {'id':data}
        if not isinstance(data, dict):
            received = type(data).__name__
            msg = self.error_messages['incorrect_type'] % received
            raise ValidationError(msg)
        if self.queryset is None:
            raise Exception('Writable related fields must include a `queryset` argument')

        try:
            return self.queryset.get(pk=data.get('id'))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            msg = self.error_messages['does_not_exist'] % smart_text(data)
            raise ValidationError(msg)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            received = type(data).__name__
            msg = self.error_messages['incorrect_type'] % received
            raise ValidationError(msg)
```

and

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = CustomRelatedField(fields=('id','name', 'number'))

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("name", "bar")
```